# Dynamically Add Fields in Access Saved Query

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, combobox, oledb

I have a `ComboBox` named `ComboBox_Calculations` in my program that is filled with calculations (ex. Current_Ratio, Total_Debt_To_Assets_Ratio).  `ComboBox_Calculations` is actually populated by using the contents of a field in a tabled called `Criteria` in my Access Database.

I need to create a saved query called `Calculations_Quarterly`.  The query needs to have fields of `Ticker`, `[Year]`, `Period` and then one field for every item in `ComboBox_Calculations`.  So for this example I would also need fields named `Current_Ratio` and `Total_Debt_To_Assets_Ratio`.

Here is what my tables look like so far:

**Criteria**
[image: Criteria]
**Calculations_Quarterly**
[image: Calculations_Quarterly]
Here is the code I have that adds one field at a time (in this case `Current_Ratio`.  But I do not know how add a column for every item in `ComboBox_Calculations`

```
con.Open()
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    Dim cmd6 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT Calculation, [Interval], Formula FROM Criteria", con)
    dr = cmd6.ExecuteReader
    dr.Read()
    Dim Calculation = dr("Calculation").ToString
    Dim Interval = dr("Interval").ToString
    Dim Formula = dr("Formula").ToString
    Dim Where_Statement As String
    If Interval = "Daily" Then
        Where_Statement = "WHERE Historical_Stock_Prices.[Date] < " & DateTime.Now.Date & ""
    ElseIf Interval = "MRQ" Then
        Where_Statement = "WHERE Income_Statements.Period < 5"
    ElseIf Interval = "TTM" Then
        Where_Statement = "WHERE Income_Statements.Period < 5"
    ElseIf Interval = "5 Year" Then
        Where_Statement = "WHERE Income_Statements.Period = 5"
    Else
        Where_Statement = ""
    End If

    Try
        Dim cmd2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("CREATE PROC " & Calculation & " AS SELECT Income_Statements.Ticker, Income_Statements.[Year], Income_Statements.Period, " & Formula & " AS " & Calculation & " FROM Income_Statements INNER JOIN Balance_Sheets ON (Income_Statements.Ticker = Balance_Sheets.Ticker) AND (Income_Statements.[Year] = Balance_Sheets.[Year]) AND (Income_Statements.Period = Balance_Sheets.Period)" & Where_Statement & "", con)
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        Dim cmd2a As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("DROP PROCEDURE " & Calculation & "", con)
        cmd2a.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim cmd2b As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("CREATE PROC " & Calculation & " AS SELECT Income_Statements.Ticker, Income_Statements.[Year], Income_Statements.Period, " & Formula & " AS " & Calculation & " FROM Income_Statements INNER JOIN Balance_Sheets ON (Income_Statements.Ticker = Balance_Sheets.Ticker) AND (Income_Statements.[Year] = Balance_Sheets.[Year]) AND (Income_Statements.Period = Balance_Sheets.Period)" & Where_Statement & "", con)
        cmd2b.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Try
con.Close
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldnt find the name of you combobox or how it is filled so assuming it is named `Combo1`, and you filled it using `Combo1.Items.Add("...")`, you would want something like this:

```
Dim sb as new System.Text.StringBuilder("")
For each s as string in Combo1.Items
  sb.Append("," & s)
Next
```

And then in your SQL:

```
Dim cmd2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("CREATE PROC " & Calculation & " AS SELECT Income_Statements.Ticker, Income_Statements.[Year], Income_Statements.Period, " & Formula & " AS " & Calculation & sb.ToString & " FROM Income_Statements INNER JOIN Balance_Sheets ON (Income_Statements.Ticker = Balance_Sheets.Ticker) AND (Income_Statements.[Year] = Balance_Sheets.[Year]) AND (Income_Statements.Period = Balance_Sheets.Period)" & Where_Statement & "", con)
```

Comment: And this will add both of the columns to my query?

Comment: This will take the items (strings) in your combo box, which I assume are the names of your columns, and add them to the select clause IE, `SELECT ...current columns... ,Current_Ratio, Total_Debt_To_Assets_Ratio FROM ...`